# Cannot start MySQL in Linux

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Have downloaded MySQL repository through the APT repository, then already did `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. But I got the error below:

```
asus@asus-K40IJ:~$ sudo mysqld
[sudo] password for asus: 
2018-11-10T04:34:58.070075Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-11-10T04:34:58.074324Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.24) starting as process 3686 ...
2018-11-10T04:34:58.077869Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

2018-11-10T04:34:58.077928Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-11-10T04:34:58.077959Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-11-10T04:34:58.078047Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Why is this and how to solve this..?

Comment: @KenWhite I have read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/changing-mysql-user.html but still confused about the `chown -R user_name /path/to/mysql/datadir`

Comment: Don't run it with sudo

Comment: $mysql  thats the proper way to run mysql

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to run 'mysqld' as root for security. But you can do it with '--user=root' option.
Please see for more details.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/security-against-attack.html